# Is it possible to make flycheck-mode and company-mode play nice together?

Tags: company-mode, flycheck

I've encountered two very nice modes when it comes to developing C++ in Emacs. First we have flycheck-mode which on the fly checks the syntax of my code using various backends such as clang or gcc. The second one is company-mode which provides auto-completion in various situations, function names, method names, object fields, using a back end such as clang.

The problem is that both likes to rewrite the contents of the buffer. Company-mode adds it's list of completions while flycheck-mode adds underscoring to problematic parts of the code. These collide for example when a user starts typing a function name, company-mode pops up the completion list, the user reads the available options which disappear half a second later because flycheck rewrites the display due to the incorrect, half-written, function call.

After further investigation it turns out that this bug only occurs in terminal emacs when the buffer can't be displayed in a single window. A video of the bug can be found on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lg40mtSk_u8

So is it possible to make these two modes play nicely together? Or are there any good alternative modes that do work together and provide the same functionality?

Comment: If you use Helm, you can use [helm-company](https://github.com/yasuyk/helm-company), replace `company-complete` with `helm-company` and company candidates are displayed in a Helm buffer instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue is the result of a faulty interaction between overlays with `before-string`/`after-string` properties whose contents have a `display` property attached.  It was been reported to Emacs as [bug #19201](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=19201), and since been fixed in Emacs.  The fix will make it into the next release.

Meanwhile, you can work around this issue by disabling Flycheck's fringe indicators in TTY frames with the following code in your init file:

```
(add-hook 'flycheck-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (display-graphic-p)
              (setq-local flycheck-indication-mode nil))))
```

You will not see any difference, since TTY frames do not have a fringe anyway, but this code will prevent Flycheck from setting a `before-string` on its overlay, thus avoiding conflicts with the Company overlays.

Comment: It appears that this only happens when emacs is in a terminal and when the window doesn't contain the whole file. I've made a bug report here with the details you requested: https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/526

Comment: @Rovanion I reverted your edit.  Aside from being wrong (you need to quote the body form with `eval-after-load`), I'd like to have an answer that reflects the current state of the art, and not that of some arbitrary older release.

Comment: Wrong? It worked just fine in my emacs. Only changed the variable when in terminal emacs.

Comment: It worked, because both `eval-after-load` and `with-eval-after-load` are unnecessary here: `setq` works just fine even if the variable isn't defined yet.

Comment: So an emacs version agnostic snippet would be just (unless (display-graphic-p)
  (setq flycheck-indication-mode nil))  ?

Comment: @Rovanion Yep. Although that might be suboptimal if you use Emacs daemon and `emacsclient` (the latter in graphical mode).

Comment: @Dmitry Which is precisely what I do. Would there perhaps be a way to redefine this variable as the buffer is switched to? But I understand that it's a hard problem since the same buffer can be viewed by tho emacsclients at the same time.

Comment: @Rovanion You should try setting the buffer-local value in `file-find-hook` with `setq-local`.

Comment: @Dmitry Good point.  I updated the answer accordingly.  I'm using `flycheck-mode-hook`, though, for Flycheck will also check buffers that have no backing file.

Comment: Shouldn't this read `unless` instead of `when`?